# Why isn't my Jquery if/click function working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a very small clicking game. In the game, there is a worker count, but you can only recruit a worker when you have collected 10 or more food. I'm sure that you all are familiar with this concept. However, the "if" statement deciding if you can purchase a worker isn't working, no matter what I try. My syntax is--to my knowledge--just fine, and so is the formatting. Is something else going wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  woodCount = 0;
  stoneCount = 0;
  foodCount = 0;
  population = 0;

  woodAdd = 1;
  stoneAdd = 1;
  foodAdd = 1;
  populationAdd = 1;

  woodWorkers = 0;
  stoneWorkers = 0;
  foodWorkers = 0;
  unemployed = 0;

  $(".wood-gather").click(function() {
    woodCount = woodCount + woodAdd;
  });
  $(".stone-gather").click(function() {
    stoneCount = stoneCount + stoneAdd;
  });
  $(".food-gather").click(function() {
    foodCount = foodCount + foodAdd;
  });

  if (foodCount >= 10) {
    $(".worker-recruit").click(function() {
      population = population + 1;
      unemployed = unemployed + 1;
      foodCount = foodCount - 10;
      console.log(population);
      console.log(foodCount);
      console.log(unemployed);
    });
  } //THIS IS THE PROBLEM CODE ^

  function CountAppend() {
    $("#WCount").remove();
    $("#WlabelDiv").append("<label for = 'woodGather' id = 'WCount'>Wood: " + woodCount + "</label>");
    $("#SCount").remove();
    $("#SlabelDiv").append("<label for = 'stoneGather' id = 'SCount'>Stone: " + stoneCount + "</label>");
    $("#FCount").remove();
    $("#FlabelDiv").append("<label for = 'foodGather' id = 'FCount'>Food: " + foodCount + "</label>");
    $("#UEM").remove();
    $("#unemployedWrap").append("<p id = 'UEM'>Unemployed: " + unemployed + "</p>");
  }
  var interval = self.setInterval(function() {
    CountAppend()
  }, 10);
});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 10px;
}

.worker-recruit {
  position: relative;
  top: 68px;
  left: 75px;
}

#PlabelDiv {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.food-gather {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  left: 84px;
}

#FlabelDiv {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>

<div class="workerWrap">
  <div id="workerRecruitWrap">
    <div id="PlabelDiv"><label for="workerRecruit">Workers:</label></div>
    <button class="worker-recruit" value="Workers" name="workerRecruit">Recruit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="jobWrap">
    <div id="unemployedWrap" style="position: absolute; top: 120px; margin-left: 10px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="foodWrap">
  <div id="foodGatherWrap">
    <div id="FlabelDiv"></div>
    <button class="food-gather" value="Food" name="foodGather">Gather</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `if` statement should be inside the click handler, not around it. Your `if` statement is just running once at the beginning of the game, before the count has been updated. So it doesn't add the click handler.

Comment: @Barmar This was the dumbest mistake I have ever made. Thank you for fixing it.

Comment: Don't feel bad, I've seen this same error many times.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code. Thank you Barmar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  woodCount = 0;
  stoneCount = 0;
  foodCount = 0;
  population = 0;

  woodAdd = 1;
  stoneAdd = 1;
  foodAdd = 1;
  populationAdd = 1;

  woodWorkers = 0;
  stoneWorkers = 0;
  foodWorkers = 0;
  unemployed = 0;

  $(".wood-gather").click(function() {
    woodCount = woodCount + woodAdd;
  });
  $(".stone-gather").click(function() {
    stoneCount = stoneCount + stoneAdd;
  });
  $(".food-gather").click(function() {
    foodCount = foodCount + foodAdd;
  });

  if (foodCount >= 10) {
    $(".worker-recruit").click(function() {
      population = population + 1;
      unemployed = unemployed + 1;
      foodCount = foodCount - 10;
      console.log(population);
      console.log(foodCount);
      console.log(unemployed);
    });
  } //THIS IS THE PROBLEM CODE ^

  function CountAppend() {
    $("#WCount").remove();
    $("#WlabelDiv").append("<label for = 'woodGather' id = 'WCount'>Wood: " + woodCount + "</label>");
    $("#SCount").remove();
    $("#SlabelDiv").append("<label for = 'stoneGather' id = 'SCount'>Stone: " + stoneCount + "</label>");
    $("#FCount").remove();
    $("#FlabelDiv").append("<label for = 'foodGather' id = 'FCount'>Food: " + foodCount + "</label>");
    $("#UEM").remove();
    $("#unemployedWrap").append("<p id = 'UEM'>Unemployed: " + unemployed + "</p>");
  }
  var interval = self.setInterval(function() {
    CountAppend()
  }, 10);
});
```